# Client data in their database

Tags: php, mysql, database, client

I have an application that stores data in a MySQL database.

But my clients would like to have their data (what they submit through the application) in their database (so we can't access their data).

So the simple solution would be:
When a client connects to the application, he enters the credentials of his database and my PHP scripts will send requests there.
Obviously this solution is really awful for UX since a client would like to be able to immediately use the app.

I could store the credentials of their database in mine but that would be exactly the same, we could access it.

Is there any way to simply implement that? Or maybe a way to store their data in my db and make this data inaccessible ?

Thanks in advance, any help or idea will be much appreciated !

Comment: Better solution ... no data no access problem... I mean what are you thinking ... application will always have access to database where data is stored...

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can have the client provide you with database credentials that only have `INSERT` privileges.  This way, you can INSERT data, but not retrieve (`SELECT`) data. So, satisfying:

> "so we can't access their data"

However, your application may not be very useful if you don't have access to previously stored data.  So, in all practicality, your application must have access to the client's data.

There is still a benefit for the client to have the data stored in their database, even if your app can access it.  They have control over the database and can revoke your access at any time.

In your case, I'd ask them for db credentials with the minimum necessary privileges and store them in your DB so they don't need to enter them every time.